# How Hasura works when a graphql query is sent to it?

Tags: graphql, hasura

Would like to know how Hasura works when a graphql query or mutation comes to the endpoint? How it processes query? How it generates schema? How it converts graphql to postgres syntax to access data?

Answer (score 1):

Here are links to the 2 main resources that should give you more insight into how Hasura is doing things internally:

1. **The query engine:** This is the core that translates GraphQL queries with access control rules to the right SQL

   https://blog.hasura.io/architecture-of-a-high-performance-graphql-to-sql-server-58d9944b8a87
2. **The Hasura metadata:** This is the Hasura configuration that gives Hasura indications on how to generate the GraphQL schema, the permissions rules etc.

   https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/how-it-works/index.html